# Determine the complete solution to the second order linear inhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the two functions:
$$2e^{-t}+e^{2t}$$ and $$3e^{t}+e^{2t}$$
They are both solutions. I have to determine the complete solution. I was thinking about this being the complete solution:
$$2e^{-t}+3e^{t}+C_1e^{2t}$$
The reason being is that e^(2t) appers in both solutions and then it needs an arbitrary real constants whilst the other two only appers once in each of the solutions. Am I correct or is it wrong? I am a bit confused.

Or do every e needs its own arbitrary real constant, so the solution becomes:
$$C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{t}+C_3e^{2t}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic should be the other way around. The parts that are common to both solutions belong to the particular solution, the variable parts are specializations of the complementary solution.

All that of course only applies if it is demanded that the linear differential equation has constant coefficients. With variable coefficients one can also find a homogeneous equation that has these functions as solutions.

The only conclusion that one can be sure about in the general case is that any convex combination of the two solutions is again a solution, that is,
$$
2ce^{-t}+3(1-c)e^t+e^{2t}.
$$

Comment: The problem is that the differential equation is unknown. All we have is the two solutions and up to three arbitrary constants which are C1, C2 and C3

Comment: The intended DE is easy to find following the first paragraph, it is $y''(t)-y(t)=3e^{2t}$.

Comment: I did not know that you could do that. That is pretty clever. Thank you. So the solution actually becomes $$C_1e^{-t}+C_2e{t}+e^{2t}$$

Comment: Can I just ask how you reverse engineered and found the differential equation from the first paragraph?

Comment: The difference of the two solutions is a solution of the homogeneous equation. This difference has two exponential terms that have to be annihilated by the second order differential operator.